# O que fazer, quando as respostas são parecidas, mas, por um detalhe tem saídas diferentes?

Tags: debate

Respondi essa questão: [Saber quantidade de checkbox selecionados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22952/6026), e fui procurar no site do jQuery. Lá tinha uma solução que se encaixava a pergunta do OP. Eu fiz a resposta, criei um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UD754/), e postei, mas, fui questionando, por pelo OP ([Ronny Amarante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4447/ronny-amarante)) com esse texto: ***Qual a diferença entre a resposta do Sergio? spam?!***, só lembrando que eu não tinha visto a resposta do outro OP e mesmo assim tem uma pequena diferença que é na saída do resultado, o meu sai em uma "div" e o outro sai em um `alert`.

Gostaria da opinião de vocês, será que isso caracteriza cópia, já visto que não foi intencional, e geralmente eu sempre observo para não ter isso? ou seria até uma outra forma de mostrar a mesma informação contribuindo com mais um estilo de resposta ?

Comment: +1 por levantar essa questão.

Comment: Tem outro exemplo aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37837/receber-array-e-gravar-v%C3%A1rias-linhas-no-mysql/37838#37838

Answer (score -1):

Desculpem, acredito que o moderador acabou levando o comentário para o lado pessoal. Eu geralmente não respondo* após uma resposta ter resolvido o problema em questão, visto que a diferença entre as 2 foram de quase 20 min ou mais. Entendo que o problema foi resolvido com outra forma, mas já havia sido solucionado. Desculpe se você levou para o pessoal.

Abrçs.

Comment: Não vejo ninguém levando para o lado pessoal. Muitas vezes quem vai responder demora mais de 20 minutos e não vê que já foi respondido. E não tem nada demais responder o que já foi respondido, já fiz isso várias vezes para agregar e o OP pode decidir mudar a resposta se a nova for melhor.

Comment: Eu sempre acho válido responder caso haja algum complemento. Caso seja a mesma resposta, não seria melhor excluir? O pessoal faz muito isso para apenas ganhar rep...

Comment: Particularmente eu excluiria, mas pense que quem respondeu pode ter gastado vários minutos do seu tempo para escrever e quer deixar lá. Não é política do SOPT forçar a exclusão de postagens parecidas.

Comment: Não levei para o lado pessoal fique tranquilo, mas, a resposta do @utluiz explicou bem o que aconteceu, levei um tempo e que aconteceu o choque de respostas. Desculpem a todos

Comment: concordo com o @utluiz. Mas caso acha que a resposta é uma repetição, sinalize e um moderador tratara do assunto, certo @utluiz?

Comment: @JorgeB. Certamente. É bom lembrar de que há 3 moderadores e o meta para discutir casos assim. Em casos mais difíceis os moderadores sempre conversam para chegar a uma decisão, levando sempre em conta as regras do site e as opiniões dos usuários.

Comment: So um detalhe, em programação existem mil formas de se atingir um mesmo objetivo, por isso hoje existem padrões a serem seguidos para tentar tornar o todo uma coisa só.... mas isso não nós impede de querer programar e desenvolver de uma maneira diferente, e claro, mostrar a nossa versão... acredito que isso ajuda toda a comunidade a crescer, ver o outro lado da moeda, enxergar uma nova maneira de atingir o mesmo objetivo, isso so agrega.

Comment: Aconteceu uma colisão de respostas comigo e com o Sérgio hoje: (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78504/arredondando-um-n%C3%BAmero-decimal-para-um-n%C3%BAmero-decimal-mais-baixo/78510#78510). Respondi uns 5 min depois, mas não havia visto a resposta dele. Coincidimos no nome do parametro casas, mas isso não significa que copiei. Essas coisas são normais, se virar rotina (mesmo usuário fazendo isso várias vezes), aí sim precisa se precoupar.